# Deployment from URL

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

Is it possible to deploy a remote war file automatically when my tomcat (6) boots?
I am thinking about pointing my context.xml to http://myrepos/myapp.war, but could not find a example of this, what is the corret attribute to set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's directly possible.

You could alter the tomcat startup script to pull down the .war file before it starts, using e.g. [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/)